# implications of excess boot options

Tags: 12.04, boot, system-installation

In addition to the currently installed 12.04, my boot menu also offers a previous version, To the best of my knowledge and ability, I have deleted all traces of previous installations prior to the latest one.  Are there two systems running side by side and would they interfere to the detriment of each other? - they both appear identical, with changes in the one reflected in the other. The system runs slowly, where prior to the latest reinstall it was fast.  I know how to remove the previous option from the boot menu, but I would like to get rid of the alternative OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an option to boot with an old kernel. It should not affect performance in any way. You can boot in the old one if you have performance issues in the new one. If you're looking to free disk space, you can [delete old kernels](https://askubuntu.com/a/153193/117893).